# How to determine how long ago a refresh token was issued in Curity

Tags: curity

In the Curity Identity Server, how can I determine how long ago a refresh token was issued? I have a custom refresh token procedure that checks `context.presentedToken.issuedAt` but this is always *now*, not when the refresh token was issued. Is this a bug or how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The issued at (`issuedAt`) claim of the presented token *should* tell you when it was issued; however, in versions up to and including 5.4.0, there was a bug that always set the presented token's issued at claim to be the current time (i.e., the time of refresh). It's easy to work around this though using the not-before (`notBefore`) claim. If you're running a build newer than 5.4, you *can* use `issuedAt` on the context's `presentedToken` object instead; both have the same value though, so there's no problem with upgrading if you were using not-before and haven't done anything special to that during issuance.

(Somewhat related, you can also get the time since the original delegation was issued. The following snipped shows this also.)

Just add this to your procedure and it should work with any version of Curity:

```js
var now = new Date() / 1000;
var secondsSinceOriginalIssuance = now - context.presentedToken.delegation.data.created;
var secondsSinceLastRefresh = now - context.presentedToken.notBefore;
```